# Add support for media keys (play, stop, previous and next buttons) in Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, media, media-buttons

How one may add support for media keys (play, stop, previous and next buttons) in Lubuntu? Solution provided at http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#What_about_the_Play.2C_Stop.2C_Previous_and_Next_buttons.3F  is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` (it may be copied from `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` )

Inside the `<keyboard>` element add the following to support Clementine (or equivalent to support other music players):

```
   <keybind key="XF86AudioPlay">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>clementine --play-pause</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioStop">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>clementine --stop</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioNext">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>clementine --next</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="XF86AudioPrev">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>clementine --previous</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
```

and run `openbox --reconfigure` to reload configuration files.

based on http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#What_about_the_Play.2C_Stop.2C_Previous_and_Next_buttons.3F and http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1183

Answer (score 0):

Although its an old question: the small tool `playerctl` allows to control various players, including spotify and youtube.

see: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-media-keys-not-working-on-linux/