# Can I control Parole with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcuts

It’s possible to control Parole by using mediakeys on the keyboard. However, if I don’t have any mediakeys, is it possible to control Parole using shortcuts?

I am using Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/585523/add-support-for-media-keys-play-stop-previous-and-next-buttons-in-lubuntu

Comment: In any case, for Parole, if you type `parole --help` in a terminal, you can see all the keyboard shortcuts you can use (play, pause, next, previous, etc). If this is not followed as duplicate, then I can provide the answer for your specific case.

Comment: thx luchonacho, works, I just bind shortcuts to parole -N (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Note: This solution is specific for Parole, but it also works with any music player, or in fact, with **any program at all**. See the last comment.

---

To configure Parole keyboard shortcuts in Xubuntu, go to the folder `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/` and open the following file **with a text editor** (double-click will open in browser):

```
xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

Now, for every command you want to bind, add the following to the file (just below any other similar line, to make sure they are correctly nested):

```
  <property name="<key name>" type="string" value="command"/>
```

For example, to call play/pause using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, add this line:

```
<property name="&lt;Control&gt;l" type="string" value="parole --play"/>
```

To get the list of command you can bind, run `parole --help` in a terminal. It will show this:

```
Usage:
  parole [OPTION…] [FILES...] - Play movies and songs

Help Options:
  -h, --help                        Show help options
  --help-all                        Show all help options
  --help-gst                        Show GStreamer Options
  --help-gtk                        Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -i, --new-instance                Open a new instance
  -n, --no-plugins                  Do not load plugins
  -d, --device                      Set Audio-CD/VCD/DVD device path
  --xv                              Enable/Disable XV support (true or false, default=true)
  -E, --embedded                    Start in embedded mode
  -F, --fullscreen                  Start in fullscreen mode
  -p, --play                        Play or pause if already playing
  -N, --next                        Next track
  -P, --previous                    Previous track
  -r, --volume-up                   Raise volume
  -l, --volume-down                 Lower volume
  -m, --mute                        Mute volume
  -u, --unmute                      Unmute (restore) volume
  -a, --add                         Add files to playlist
  -V, --version                     Print version information and exit
  --display=DISPLAY                 X display to use
```

Finally, to bind keys for another program, run in terminal using `--help` option (for example, `gmusicbrowser --help`), and the options available will come up, as above.